# Trouble using .indexOf() with .filter()

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, indexof

Newbie to javascript and es6 here.  I'm building a react-native app with firebase and redux.  One of my action creators is really just a search bar function.  I'm fetching data from Firebase with this code:

```
export const searchResult = () => {
  const { currentUser } = firebase.auth();
  return (dispatch) => {
    firebase.database().ref(`/users/${currentUser.uid}/entries`)
      .on('value', snapshot => {
        const obj = snapshot.val();
```

That part of the function is working swimmingly. Then I want to turn the data into an array, instead of just some objects.

```
  const array1 = Object.keys(obj).map(function(key) {
    return [obj[key]];
});
```

And again, this executes perfectly. It's the next bit of code that I'm for certain is wrong, just don't know how to fix it.  I'm wanting to return a filter of array1 according to what goes in the search bar. Here I have search bar hard-coded to element (I'll switch that once I get the code working).

```
      const element = '0';
      const array2 = array1.filter(array1.indexOf(element) !== -1);


        dispatch({ type: SEARCH_RESULT_SUCCESS, payload: array2 });
      });
  };
};
```

As of now, I'm pretty sure this is just returning a boolean of false, instead of returning objects from the array that match element. Do I need another function in here to bridge my logic? What am I missing? Any help is much appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: `array1.filter(array1.indexOf(element) !== -1)` is not throwing an error? the argument for filter should be a function something like `array1.filter((arr1Elem) => array1.indexOf(element) !== -1)`

Comment: Oh! That's totally it. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide a function callback to `filter` method.

```
  const element = '0';
  const array2 = array1.filter((arr1Elem) => array1.indexOf(element) !== -1);


    dispatch({ type: SEARCH_RESULT_SUCCESS, payload: array2 });
  });
  };
};
```